# Is it possible to implement a C# Interface and extend the arguments of Events?

Tags: c#, winforms

Suppose I have the following Interface:

```
interface IBook
{
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> PageChanged;
}
```

which I could implement without difficulty for this class:

```
class Novel : IBook
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> PageChanged;

    protected void OnPageChanged()
    {
        EventHandler<EventArgs> pageChanged = PageChanged;
        if (pageChanged != null) pageChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

however, if I now have an object called `Encyclopedia` defined as:

```
class Encyclopedia : IBook
{
    public class EncyclopediaEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int Volume
        {
            get { return volume; }
        }

        private int volume;

        public EncyclopediaEventArgs(int volume)
        {
            this.volume = volume;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<EncyclopediaEventArgs> PageChanged;

    protected void OnPageChanged(int volume)
    {
        EventHandler<EncyclopediaEventArgs> pageChanged = PageChanged;
        if (pageChanged != null) pageChanged(this, new EncyclopediaEventArgs(volume));
    }
}
```

which has all the workings of a `Book`, but with the added event argument field of `Volume`.  When I compile, I get an error (as surmised I would):

> error CS0738: 'Encyclopedia' does not implement interface member 'IBook.PageChanged'. 'Encyclopedia.PageChanged' cannot implement 'IBook.PageChanged' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.EventHandler'

It states that it cannot implement `IBook.PageChanged` because `System.EventHandler<System.EventArgs>` is not the return type, even though `EncyclopediaEventArgs` derives from `System.EventArgs`.

My question, therefore, is, would it be possible to derive such a class as `Encyclopedia` which adds the additional `Volume` field to its event arguments?

(Any discussion is very much welcome as to why this is or is not a poor design/architecture decision!)

Comment: Move it to a generic type parameter of the interface.

Comment: You don't inherit interfaces. You implement interfaces. You inherit from classes.

Comment: You don't need to extend the type, just try casting wherever needed

Comment: You could explicitly implement the `IBook` interface, then add an `OnPageChanged` Event with the new arguments to the derived class.  Consumers of the derived class can handle the event with the enhanced event arguments, consumers of `IBook` can handle the `IBook` event.

Comment: Should 'private int volume;' variable declaration be at the beginning of the class?

Comment: @TingShunNg I always list properties first, then fields, then members in the order public, protected, then private in alphabetical order.  This is just my style preference, the compiler doesn't care.

Comment: Also: Beware the generic parameter on such an interface, it can make the interface itself useless in some cases, such as making a `List<MyInterface<NowWhat>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems fairly straight forward to do this:

```
interface IBook<T> where T : EventArgs
{
    event EventHandler<T> PageChanged;
}

class Novel : IBook<EventArgs> { ... }

class Encyclopedia : IBook<Encyclopedia.EncyclopediaEventArgs> { ... }
```

If you still need a plain `IBook` then you would do this:

```
interface IBook { }

interface IBook<T> : IBook where T : EventArgs
{
    event EventHandler<T> PageChanged;
}
```

Comment: First solution using generics is best one here.  Accepted.  Thank-you!

Answer (score 2):

It depends a bit on how you are going to use `IBook`. You could create a generic parameter for the `EventArgs` like so:

```
public interface IBook<TEventArgs> where TEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    event EventHandler<TEventArgs> PageChanged;
}

public class Novel : IBook<EventArgs>
{
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> PageChanged;
}

public class Encyclopedia : IBook<EncyclopediaEventArgs>
{
    event EventHandler<EncyclopediaEventArgs> PageChanged;
}
```

But then you can't use `IBook` without the generic type if you need `PageChanged` for other purposes.

Another way is to just keep the `event EventHandler<EventArgs> PageChanged;` have the Encyclopedia implementation pass a `EncyclopediaEventArgs` and just cast in the event handler.

```
class Encyclopedia : IBook
{
    public class EncyclopediaEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> PageChanged;

    protected void OnPageChanged(int volume)
    {
        EventHandler<EventArgs> pageChanged = PageChanged;
        if (pageChanged != null) pageChanged(this, new EncyclopediaEventArgs(...));
    }
}

public class BookReader
{
    public void OnPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Encyclopedia && e is EncyclopediaEventArgs)
        {
            EncyclopediaEventArgs ee = (EncyclopediaEventArgs)e;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice differentiation when are generics a problem

Comment: @Mark very nice explanation and solution, wish it would let me accept both.  Thank-you!